# sonar runner stuck at Java AST Scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

We are using sonar runner 2.3 to analyze java code.

sonar-runner gets stuck at one of our projects. The last message on the console reads Java AST Scan and process gets stuck at that..

```
[jsaluja@[Proj1]] ~/sonar-runner-2.3/bin/sonar-runner
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.6.0_21 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit)
Linux 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/jsaluja/sonar-runner-2.3/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /home/jsaluja/0809/Proj1/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /home/jsaluja/0809/Proj1/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 3.6.2
15:53:51.076 INFO  - Load batch settings
15:53:51.197 INFO  - User cache: /home/jsaluja/.sonar/cache
15:53:51.201 INFO  - Install plugins
15:53:52.129 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
15:53:52.137 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4/XE
15:53:54.574 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
15:53:57.857 INFO  - Load project settings
15:53:58.157 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
15:53:58.440 INFO  - -------------  Scan Module1
15:53:58.444 INFO  - Load module settings
15:54:00.618 INFO  - Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
15:54:00.631 INFO  - Excluded tests:
15:54:00.631 INFO  -   **/package-info.java
15:54:00.703 INFO  - Configure Maven plugins
15:54:00.764 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis
15:54:00.783 INFO  - Compare over 5 days (2013-08-11)
15:54:00.796 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2013-07-17)
15:54:00.968 INFO  - Base dir: /home/jsaluja/0809/Proj1/Module1
15:54:00.968 INFO  - Working dir: /home/jsaluja/0809/Proj1/.sonar/a.b.c.d_Module1
15:54:00.968 INFO  - Source dirs: /home/jsaluja/0809/Proj1/Module1/src
15:54:00.968 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
15:54:01.221 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
15:54:11.517 INFO  - Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 10296 ms
15:54:11.518 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
15:54:11.618 INFO  - Java AST scan...
```

I have waited for over 2 hours.

The project structure

```
Proj1
    Module1
    Module2
```

sonar-project.properties

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=a.b.c.d:Proj1
sonar.projectName=Proj1
sonar.projectVersion=1234

# List of the module identifiers
sonar.modules=Module1,Module2
```

Comment: what does the sonar log file shows? <SONAR_HOME>/logs/*